# A problem when clicking on the phone does not appear in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

A problem when clicking on the phone does not appear in Selenium , I would like to run this code.

- The phone number appears in the regular browser without Selenium.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver_path = r"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"


options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.binary_location = driver_path


driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)


url = "https://www.dubizzle.com.eg/en/ad/198522215"
driver.get(url)

try:
    
    button = WebDriverWait(driver, 2000).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Show phone number']/ancestor::button"))
    )


    button.click()


    phone_number = WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='_45d98091 ae608d5a a59f5caf be13fe44']/ancestor::button/following-sibling::span"))
    ).text

    print("Phone number:", phone_number)

finally:

    driver.quit()
```

I tried it more than once

Comment: You have not explained the actual problem.  "when clicking on the phone does not appear" is not specific enough.

Comment: If this code produces errors or unwanted results, you have to **show them**.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.